# Can an access token outlive a refresh token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, openid-connect

I have read various docs from PingIdentity, Microsoft, auth0 and even the [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.4) in trying to answer a simple question: can an access token outlive a refresh token? The context is OAuth 2.0.

Let me explain with an example. Say we have a refresh token with a time-to-live (TTL) of 10 days. Each access token has a TTL of 3 days. They were issues at 00:00 on day 1. Given that we only refresh these access tokens at the edge of expiration, that means we get an access token on day 1, 4, 7 and 10. Now, does that last access token expire after one day (at the end of day 10) or after three days (end of day 12)?

In [this recent article from Microsoft on LinkedIn authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/programmatic-refresh-tokens), they indicate the first option: the access token would expire at the same time as the refresh token, being issued with a TTL of just one day (well, slightly less probably), instead of three days. Others do not indicate anything and simply skip over the matter, relying on the fact that short-lived access tokens make the discussion meaningless. But sometimes (like in the article) these access tokens live for weeks and the refresh token lives for a year, which is a whole different ballpark than the 5 minute lifetimes.

My guess is that this is implementation/vendor dependant since it is not explicitly stated in any RFC (that I could find).

Comment: If you only issue an access token for the remaining time left on the refresh token, then you could potentially be issuing a token valid for seconds or minutes left. I think it makes more sense to use an access token that expires in hours, not days, then you are more comfortable issueing the token even with the refresh token expiring soon. Then the logic is simpler for the client, if I have a valid refresh token, I will be able to get an access token that I can expect to last for x time.

Comment: @ryanm I was not asking for implementation input. It was about understanding to what extent the lifetime of a refresh and access token was defined in the spec. The example I used above was just a pedagogical means to an end. You can replace "days" with "minutes" if it helps convey the point: does the final access token expire along with the refresh token, or is its lifetime independent of the identity providers setting for the refresh token.

Answer (score 0):

The receiver (like an API) of an access token never sees the refresh token, so the receiver will accept the access token as long as it is valid (not expired).

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it does not touch upon the question I asked :)